# Work = rate * time problems

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Normally when we work with these problems, for example,

> Student A writes 2 essays each hour.  Student B writes 3 essays each hour.  If they worked together without interfering each other, how long does it take to finish 1 essay?

I would think that it is natural to first find out the combined rates and then use the $W=rt$ formula to solve the problem.

However, one of my student claimed that as long as the units match up, we are able to combine the numbers and still use it to solve the problem.  So this is what my student did.

First he found $1/2$ hour per essay and $1/3$ hour per essay.  So $1/2+1/3$ hours per essay is needed and therefore, to finish 1 essay one needs $6/5$ hours.

I clearly see intuitively the fact that taking longer time to finish an essay does not sound right, but mathematically I cannot explain why the students logic does not work.

I am assuming that there is a way to get to the answer using the student's argument, so it would be helpful if someone could

1), explain to me why mathematically the student's logic does not fit

2), explain to me if there is any method to make his work actually reach the correct answer.

Comment: One way to challenge the logic is to ask them how many essays they'd make in 6 hours. From the problem statement, it'll clearly be $2*6+3*6=5*6=30$ essays in six hours, a rate of 1 essay per 1/5-th of an hour. His framing _would_ work if one person had to check the work of the other, so that it'd take 20+30=50 minutes altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Use the formula $W=(r_A +r_B)t$ where $r_A$ and $r_B$ are the rates of doing work (essays per hour) for students $A$ and $B$ respectively.

In your example, $r_A=2$ essays per hour, $r_B=3$ essays per hour, and $W=1$ essay. Substitute in formula and solve for $t$.

$t=\frac W{r_A+r_B}=\frac 1{2+3}=\frac 1{5}$ hours.

This assumes, of course, that Student $A$ would write $\frac 2{5}$ of that essay while Student $B$ would simultaneously write the remainder -- a bit of a stretch.